# Automate the requirements.txt file install with pip for git password

Tags: pip, requirements.txt

I have a requirements.txt file that has some packages from a private repo. When I run the command `pip install -r requirements.txt` it prompts me to enter username and password for this repo.

I am wondering if there is a way to supply that to it or use some sort of environment variable that it gets the username and password?

e.g.

```
boto3
myproject@git+https://git.my-repo.com/com/bla.git@ksdidmop1012m
```

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/authentication/

Comment: @sinoroc That's about authenticating to PyPI. The OP asks about authenticating to a private Git repository: `pip install git+https://` or `pip install git+ssh://`

Comment: @phd Original question did not mention anything about "git", only about a "private repo", or I missed it :) -- Anyway, as far as I know, if it is `git+https` then the link still applies, if it is `git+ssh` then the usual SSH credentials solutions apply. No? -- It is probably a duplicate question anyway.

Comment: "*if it is `git+https` then the link still applies,*" I don't use `pip` with private repos so I can only hope it is. "*if it is `git+ssh` then the usual SSH credentials solutions apply.*" Yes, absolutely.